# how to find and erase a certain character in vector elements

Tags: c++

As you know we use std::find for finding an element.

But assume that we have a vector and we want to find a certain character like "^" in the elements of that vector.
So how could we do that ?

For example Look at this Code:

```
int main () {
    vector<string> myvector;

    myvector.push_back("a^b");
    myvector.push_back("a");
    myvector.push_back("cd^");

    myvector.erase(find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), "^"));

    for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++)
      std::cout << ' ' << myvector.at(i) << "\t";

    return 0;
}
```

As you see, I just wanna find and erase all "^" characters but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the std algorithm with c11 function

```
for (string& str : myvector){
  str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '^'),str .end());
}
```

it should work

Comment: This is removing strings from the vector, not characters from the strings.

Comment: i edit the code to do what you wanted to do , i've write too fast the first time

Comment: auto is not needed here because you know what the type of the input and with string the intellisense give you the right function immediately (no grammatical resolution needed ) but with "auto&" it works

Comment: what about it If we want just find position of that character ? Not remove it.

Comment: replace the line str.erase by str.find("^");  go there to know more about string function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to erase a character from each string, `vector::erase` won't help you - that can only let you erase the strings that are exactly `"^"`. You will have to iterate over each `string` in the `vector`, and use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
for (auto& str : myvector) {
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '^'), str.end());
}
```

If you can't use C++11, you can write a function to do the erasing:

```
void erase_carets(std::string& str) {
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '^'), str.end());
}

std:for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), erase_carets);
```

Comment: I think it should be str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '^'), end(str)); otherwise only one character will be erased

Comment: Thanks to answer.
After i did that , I saw that nothing happened.
even one of the characters will not remove

Comment: And this Also Worked . Tanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Barry's answer, if you've got boost as an alternative, traverse throughout your vector container and use `boost::erase_all`, defined under `boost/algorithm/string.hpp`

```
for(auto& i : myvector)
    boost::erase_all(i, "^");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
vector<string>::iterator it = myvector.begin()

while(it != myvector.end())
{
    string theCurrentWord = myvector[it];

    theCurrentWord.erase(std::remove_if(string.begin(), string.end(),std::"^"), string.end());

}
```

Comment: Did you try this out?

Comment: instead of string it should b theCurrentWord which is name of string, i think that is enough

Comment: But did you try it out?

Comment: No :( , but I had used this type of code in my previous game. So at least user get slight idea what he can do. :)

Comment: I guess that game is still running then.

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.